# Font is giving different output compared to figma

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, typography

I'm using [Gilroy-Bold](https://github.com/chrisbull/font-collection/tree/master/Gilroy) as my font and getting different results in figma than my react application. They are both used from the same source.

Figma:

[image]

My Laptop:

[image]

This how I'm implementing it.

```
@font-face {
 font-family:'Gilroy-Bold';
 src:url('/src/Gilroy/Gilroy-Bold.ttf');
}

.PPNameHeader{
   color: #444BAB;
   margin:0px;
   margin-left: 6%;
   font-size: 1.173rem;
   font-family:Gilroy-Bold;
}
```

Path is correct as I went through my editor recommendation.
Thing I have tried:

```
*{
  font-family:'Gilroy-Bold';
  src:url('/src/Gilroy/Gilroy-Bold.ttf');
}
```

Cleared my cache.

Incognito tab.

Restarted the development server and editor.

Comment: Can you put the `.ttf` file in the same directory as your CSS file and change the path to `'Gilroy-Bold.tff'`, just to make *sure* it isn't the path.

Comment: @EddieReeder On it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Now that we know it's your path causing the issue, it's best practice to use a *relative url* for your `src`. You're using an *absolute url*, which can evaluate to different locations depending on the environment its in.

```css
src:url('/path/from/root/Gilroy-Bold.ttf'); /* absolute url */
src:url('./path/from/current/file/Gilroy-Bold.ttf'); /* relative url */
```

2. When applying a custom font-family, it's name is usually encased in quotes. I'm not sure if this is necessary, but it could be something to try:

```
.PPNameHeader{
   ...
   font-size: 1.173rem;
   font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold';
}
```